# Joining 2 regex rules into one

Tags: regex

Is there a special character to join to groups of rules in regex

I need to match the first 2 chars and the last 2 number in every row

This match the first 2 chars

```
(^..)
```

this match the last 2 numbers

```
([0-9][0-9]$)
```

How to join those 2 rules?
Tried that withou success

```
(^..)([0-9][0-9]$)
```

Comment: Which language/environment/regex flavor are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(^..).*([0-9][0-9]$)
```

You can use the .* modifer to match 'everything in between'

Comment: But I want to exclude everything in between. I just need the first 2 letters and the last 2 digits

Comment: the brackets are the regex 'captures'. Since the .* is not inside a bracked it will not be captured. Only the first 2 letters and the last 2 digits will be captured.

Answer (score 4):

Well you need to match the parts in between as well. Just allow for arbitrarily many arbitrary characters:

```
(^..).*([0-9][0-9]$)
```

Note that in most flavors `.` does not match line breaks. If your input may contain line breaks, use the `s` ("single line" or sometimes "dotall") modifier, to change `.`s meaning. Otherwise (i.e. in JavaScript) use `[\s\S]*`.

Also note that it might be easier, more readable and more efficient to just use two regexes consecutively:

```
^..
[0-9][0-9]$
```

No need for grouping/capturing and repetition.

**EDIT:**

Note that these two aren't completely equivalent. The first one requires at least four characters (because the two characters matched by `..` cannot be matched again by `[0-9][0-9]`) while the second one could just contain two digits (in which case the `..` would match those same digits). It depends on which of these semantics you are looking for. A third solution that uses only one regex but is equivalent to the two-regex solution would use lookaheads:

```
^(?=(..))(?=.*([0-9][0-9])$)
```

This would allow you to match `x12`, the first capture being `x1` and the second being `12`.

Thanks for [Alan Moore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20938/alan-moore) for [pointing this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373650/joining-2-regex-rules-into-one/17373669?noredirect=1#comment25218780_17373669).

Comment: Drat. Beat me by 3 seconds :)

Comment: @TimPietzcker you won earlier ;). Wow 5 identical answers. I think I haven't seen that before.

Comment: Your two solutions are not equivalent.  The first one requires the string to be at least four characters long, while the second will match strings like `x12` (returning `x1` and `12`) and `12` (returning `12` for both values).

Comment: Thanks... but those expressions match the whole line. It is matching the text in between too. I need to match in on expression just the first 2 letter and the last 2 numbers. I have all the lines ending in 2 numbers.

Comment: @GuilhermeLongo again, what language or environment are you using? there will be a way to access those two things, as they are [captured](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) by the parentheses

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `anything goes here` - also known as .*

```
(^..).*([0-9][0-9]$)
```

Comment: It is match the text in between too. I need to match in on expression just the first 2 letter and the last 2 numbers. I have all the lines ending in 2 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If the row contains additional characters between the "first two" and the "last two", then you'll need something in the regex to match the intervening characters; something like:

```
(^..).*([0-9][0-9]$)
```